# See the output of a script run by another program

Tags: bash, python-2.7

i have a program (domoticz) which launches a python script by a bash command finished by a & (but it is the same without &). (under raspbian)
Therefore i have a "process". Here the output of ps aux:

```
root     16768  0.5  1.8  11832  8908 ?        S    11:45   0:00 python2.7 /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/python/ecs_bain.py
```

I would like to see the outpput of the python script without storing it into a file. Is it possible?

I already try what i found on stackoverflow :

> cat /proc/ID/fg/1

to try to see the output but there is nothing in the file.

> fg/jobs commands (in root and pi users)

but it answers: no such job

So how can i see the output of a "background" script.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you say `without storing it into a file`? do you have a reason for it?

Comment: First, i would like to not store on the SD Card to prevent it and because generally i don't need the information. It is in the case of. Indeed, i can store the output into a file in the ram (ramlog,...) and delete it each day. But i looking after a way which can be used for every script launched (with and without output file)